# Remove XML objects if they contain certain values

Tags: xml, vim, csv, xml-parsing

I have a large XML document (13MB) containing objects (products with product SKU's, names, etc.).

I also have a large list (CSV, 700 items) of product SKU's for each product that should be removed from my XML doc.

If a product in the XML doc contains a SKU from my list, I want to remove the entire product/object from the XML doc.

Here's an example of the XML structure:

```
<product>
  <Product_ID><![CDATA[1]]></Product_ID>
  <Product_Name><![CDATA[First product]]></Product_Name>
  <Product_CodeSKU><![CDATA[0000001]]></Product_CodeSKU>
</product>
<product>
  <Product_ID><![CDATA[2]]></Product_ID>
  <Product_Name><![CDATA[Second product]]></Product_Name>
  <Product_CodeSKU><![CDATA[0000002]]></Product_CodeSKU>
</product>
<product>
  <Product_ID><![CDATA[3]]></Product_ID>
  <Product_Name><![CDATA[Third product]]></Product_Name>
  <Product_CodeSKU><![CDATA[0000003]]></Product_CodeSKU>
</product>
```

My list (CSV) contains values like "0000001". I'd like to find any products that contain that value, and remove them – while leaving other products untouched.

Comment: And you want to do this in... vim?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you struggling? I find it slightly questionable to let StackOverflow solve the problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so first: if I were doing this more than once, then I'd make a nice Perl script to do it for me in a completely automated fashion. Then other people can use it too, not just us Vim nerds. And I say Perl because that's what I know; others will say python or Ruby or whatever their chosen language is, but regardless: for repeated use, Vim is the wrong tool for this.

HOWEVER, sometimes you just want to get something done quickly and it's probably not going to be a very common task.

To tackle this in Vim, I would open the CSV in a split buffer alongside the XML file.

1. Place the cursor on the first line of the CSV file.
2. Start recording a macro into a register of your choice. For example, `qa`
3. Execute a generic command that will always position the cursor on the SKU to remove no matter what line you're on.
4. `yiw` (or some other command to yank the entire SKU).
5. `<C-W>w` to switch windows to the XML file.
6. `:g#<C-R>0` to start a :g command and insert the SKU as the pattern. You may need to tweak this to only match real SKU lines if there are false positives.
7. Finish the `:g` command with a normal command to delete the entire tag, for example `:g#0000001#norm! vatatVd`
8. Return to the CSV file with `<C-w>p`
9. Move to the next line in the CSV file with `j`
10. Stop recording the macro with `q`.
11. Test repeating the macro once (for example, `@a`).
12. If the test fails, repeat steps 1-10 until you get a repeatable macro.
13. If (10) works as intended, repeat as many times as necessary, e.g. `9999999@a`

Answer (score 2):

In Vimscript, assuming a UNIX-based system:

```
fun! ClearSKUs()
  let command = "cat " . input("Enter path to CSV file: ")
  let data = system(command) | redraw!
  let values = split(substitute(data, "\n", "", ""), ",")
  for value in values
    if search(value) > 0
      silent ?<product?,/<\/product/d
    endif
  endfor
endfun

command! ClearSKUs call ClearSKUs()
```

To run, when editing the XML document, use:

```
:ClearSKUs
```

**EDIT:** Updated to replace `match()` with `search()` as @Ben mentioned, and to use a single normal command.

**EDIT 2:** Updated to replace normal command with range given to `d` (thanks, @Ben!) and clear prompt after input is received.

Comment: How about using a range with the `:d` command instead of normal mode commands to set up a visual area and delete it, since you're using searches anyway? Something like `?<product?,/<\/product/d` could replace your second two normal commands I think. Also you could `call search()` instead of the normal command for searching to make it cleaner.

Comment: @Ben I am relatively new to Vimscript, so didn’t think of these. :) Thanks. `search()` certainly is simpler than my use of `match()`, and although I haven’t been able to come up with a working range for `d` as you suggested I’ve at least discovered that I don’t need two normal commands to remove the lines.

Comment: I made the `:d` change and it works for me. Does work for you, too? See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges#Ranges_with_marks_and_searches for more examples why this works.

Comment: @Ben I got notified of your edit but was apparently not allowed to vote on it (not enough reputation?), or I would have accepted it -- sorry. :( Yes, that worked; I think I was just confused on how to do this in Vimscript as opposed to in Vim by hand. It is in the answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet...>

<xsl:variable name="removals" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('skus.csv'), '\n')"/> 

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product[Product_CodeSKU = $removals]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Seems a lot simpler than @Ben's solution to me, and vastly faster.

Might need a little bit of adjustment because the format of the CSV file isn't clear to me.

Comment: If you know XSLT already...I'm sure that is faster and probably simpler. As I said, Vim is *not* the right tool for this. But, not knowing XSLT, and knowing how to do it it Vim; learning how to use XSLT for a one-time task would slow me down.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I would be equally reluctant to learn Vim. But if you're working with XML and not using XSLT, that's a bit like working with wood and not using a chisel. It's time you learnt it, and I was keen to show how simple it is for routine problems like this.